# A question about index of the commutant in a Moufang loop

Tags: non-associative-algebras

Let $M$ be a *non-commutative Moufang loop* and $C(M)$ be its *commutant*. I can prove that the index of $C(M)$ in $M$, $|M:C(M)|$, is greater than or equal to 4.  Also, I can show that $|M:Z(M)|\geq 4$, where $Z(M)$ is the *center* of $M$ and if $M/Z(M)$ be cyclic then $M$ must be commutative (just like as groups -as associative
Moufang loops. Infact these assertions generalize the similar results in groups). 
  Now, my question is:

> **Is there any better lower bound for these indices**?

(My evidences are calculations in GAP with *library of small Moufang loops* which show that $|M:Z(M)\geq 8$ and $|M:C(M)|\geq 8$.)

I appreciate any hint, remark or comment in advance.

Comment: There seems to be an extra $\$ $ sign in your penultimate sentence.

Comment: The label "loop groups" is inappropriate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_group

Comment: The esitmates cannot be improved in general, because for example
the quaternion group $Q$ satisfies $[Q:Z(Q)]=4$.